# How to avoid Maximum call stack size exceeded in Observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have filtered list:

```
  public filteredEvents$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);
```

And method that inverts propery `checked_export` and pushed changes back:

```
  public checkAll(): void {
    this.filteredEvents$
      .pipe(
        map((events: IEvent[]) => {
          return events.map((event: IEvent) => {
            event.checked_export = !event.checked_export;
            return event;
          });
        })
      )
      .subscribe((events) => this.filteredEvents$.next(events));
  }
```

Template is:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of filteredEvents$ | async">
```

Obviously I get error:

```
ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I can push chnages to `this.selectedEvents$` like:

```
  public checkAll(): void {
    this.filteredEvents$
      .pipe(
        map((events: IEvent[]) => {
          return events.map((event: IEvent) => {
            event.checked_export = !event.checked_export;
            return event;
          });
        })
      )
      .subscribe((events) => this.selectedEvents$.next(events));
  }
```

But it calls always this line:

```
 public export(): void {
    this.eventService.selectedEvents$
      .pipe().subscribe((fileid) => {});
}
```

My problem is to modify current `this.filteredEvents$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are receiving maximum call stack size exceeded is because you have an infinite loop, you are subscribing to `filteredEvents$`, then in the subscription you are emitting value to `filteredEvents$`, which triggers the subscription again, effectively causing an infinite loop.

You can just remove the `subscribe`, the `async` pipe automatically subscribe to changes and by using `pipe` you will be able to transform the data however you want:

```js
  public checkAll(): void {
    this.filteredEvents$ = this.filteredEvents$
      .pipe(
        map((events: IEvent[]) => {
          return events.map((event: IEvent) => {
            event.checked_export = !event.checked_export;
            return event;
          });
        })
      )
  }
```

As you're using a BehaviorSubject and can't assign an Observable to it, you can subscribe once using `take(1)`, this way it won't be triggered again:

```js
  public checkAll(): void {
    this.filteredEvents$
      .pipe(
       take(1),
        map((events: IEvent[]) => {
          return events.map((event: IEvent) => {
            event.checked_export = !event.checked_export;
            return event;
          });
        })
      )
      .subscribe((events) => this.selectedEvents$.next(events));
  }
```

The reason this will work is because `take will take the first n number of emissions and then unsubscribe for you.

Comment: Type 'Observable<IEvent[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'BehaviorSubject<IEvent[]>': _value, value, getValue, next,

Comment: The same error with take(1): `public filteredEvents$ = new BehaviorSubject<IEvent[]>([]);`

Comment: The same: `Type 'Observable<IEvent[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'BehaviorSubject<IEvent[]>': _value, value, getValue, next, and 9`

Comment: Share a stackblitz, and make sure you copy the second code snippet because I think you're using the first one

Comment: I can post in question, only this method, it is all I have

Comment: All I adde to the second snippet was take(1), so no reason to receive a type error. Again, please check your code and make sure it matches the snippet or add take(1) to the first part of the pipe in the original code, I can't do this for you.

Comment: My result method is: `public checkAll(): void {
    this.filteredEvents$ = this.filteredEvents$.pipe(
      map((events: IEvent[]) => {
        return events.map((event: IEvent) => {
          event.checked_export = !event.checked_export;
          return event;
        });
      })
    );
  }
`

Comment: Like I said you are using the first snipper. Use this:   public checkAll(): void {
    this.filteredEvents$
      .pipe(
       take(1),
        map((events: IEvent[]) => {
          return events.map((event: IEvent) => {
            event.checked_export = !event.checked_export;
            return event;
          });
        })
      )
      .subscribe((events) => this.selectedEvents$.next(events));
  }

Comment: I want to use your first snippet