# Add value into stream using RxJS: maximum call stack size

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have websocket server and Apollo client/server and RxJS to detect changes in my environment. And a service which subscribes users to that websocket:

// SessionService

```js
  private sessionsSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Array<Session> | null>(null);
  public sessions$ = this.sessionsSubject.asObservable();

  constructor(private apollo: Apollo) {this.subscribeToSessions()}

  public subscribeToSessions(): void {
    this.apollo.subscribe<SessionCreated>({
      query: sessionOperations.CREATE_SESSION_SUBSCRIPTION
    }).subscribe(async ({data}) => {
      this.sessions$.subscribe({
        next: (sessions) => this.setSessions([...sessions??[], data!.sessionCreated]),
        complete: () => console.log('complete')
      })
    })
  }

  public setSessions(sessions: Array<Session>): void {
    this.sessionsSubject.next(sessions)
  }
}
```

If a new session is added the `sessionOperations.CREATE_SESSION_SUBSCRIPTION` query is called which I subscribe to. In the subscribe I want to update the sessions with the newly created session.

But *I think* this is causing an infinite loop. Since this also updates the `sessions$` observable which runs the adding of a session again.

Comment: Why subscribe to `sessions$` inside of the Apollo subscription? If you want to push new Apollo sessions into `sessions$`, couldn’t you just call `setSessions` directly inside of the Apollo callback instead of as the `next` method on a `sessions$` subscription? I’m not sure I’m following what you’re trying to accomplish.

Comment: The Apollo subscribe is a WebSocket subscription. So when that fires I want to do "something". This something is pushing the session (returned by the Apollo WebSocket) into the `sessions$` stream. But here's the trouble. The sessions stream only accepts an array  of sessions, which is why I subscribe to to `sessions$` stream, then I add the returned session to the array and push that again.

Answer (score 0):

You are in an infinite loop because inside a subscribe you call next on the observable you are subscribed to and cause `Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

`this.setSessions([...sessions??[], data!.sessionCreated])` should replace the whole subscription to the behavior subject so that just the outer subscription is pushed into the behavior subject without triggering an infinite loop.

```js
const { BehaviorSubject } = rxjs;

const sessionsSubject = new BehaviorSubject(null);
const sessions$ = sessionsSubject.asObservable();

sessions$.subscribe({
  next: (sessions) => { setSessions([...(sessions||[]), 'Some Session object']); },
  // This causes the observable to emit which is what triggers the infinite loop
  complete: () => console.log('complete')
  // This is a behavior subject it will only complete if you do it manually
});

function setSessions(sessions) {
  sessionsSubject.next(sessions);
}

setSessions(['Some Session object']);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer here > [How to avoid Maximum call stack size exceeded in Observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65623050/how-to-avoid-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-in-observable) was relevant for me:

```js
public subscribeToSessions(): void {
  this.apollo.subscribe<SessionCreated>({
    query: sessionOperations.CREATE_SESSION_SUBSCRIPTION
  }).subscribe(async ({data}) => {
    this.sessions$
    .pipe(
      take(1),
    ).subscribe({
      next: (sessions) => data ? this.setSessions([...sessions??[], data.sessionCreated]) : null,
    })
  })
}
```

Adding the `take(1)` solved my issue.

> The take operator allows us to specify how many values we want to receive from the Observable before we unsubscribe. This means that when we receive the specified number of values, take will automatically unsubscribe!

Comment: I believe you could also use `sessionsSubject.getValue()` to retrieve the current value without subscribing. Either solution should work :)